# PHP Escape All Characters In String

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I am using PHP's password_hash() to store some of my passwords and I want to echo and get the stored hash from my database. However, when I try to I keep getting errors because certain characters aren't escaped. Now the hashing, as it is random, I need a way to just get the raw data from the database without PHP sending me errors when I just want to echo out a simple line like:

```
echo "$2y$10$LYTZuvb7Ff2NeqxLjkp3KeZQmBrq3iaZ4eeY/cuUqz2nGA6wYgENq";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given what you posted for code and if I am getting what you're asking is that you need to encase the echo'd line in single quotes.

```
echo '$2y$10$LYTZuvb7Ff2NeqxLjkp3KeZQmBrq3iaZ4eeY/cuUqz2nGA6wYgENq';
```

*Why?* Because, the `$` signs are interpreted as variable assignments in doubled quotes and PHP is trying to parse them as such.

It may even throw undefined variables notices.

You can also [`var_dump()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) the said row/variable or echo the row from the query.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Thanks!